# Is there a way to run a script when a record is deleted in ListViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am developing a core data application based on the CoreData books example. Is there a way to run a short piece of code after the user clicks the edit button and then selects and deletes the record in the ListViewController? I would like to do this after each deletion, not just when the user stops editing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the user deletes a row from a `UITableView`, the table view's data source receives a `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` message.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to run code (not "a script") when deleting an object in a table view?

If some additional model-level work needs to be done when deleting an object, then the object should implement that itself.  There are hooks where you can do that in your subclasses of NSManagedObject.  You could also have your own controller-level object observe notifications from the NSManagedObjectContext and make the appropriate adjustments as a result.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was deleting a person's location, and when it was deleted, I wanted to change the location to "Unfiled".  I do not know how to do that other than by doing a fetch request and changing this manually.